# How to override action_registry js in odoo [12.0]

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-12

I have the following js file that handles a widget and I would like to overwrite and add code for custom events function, but when I tried to instantiate, nothing seems to be on the object:

This a reference for the script that I want to overwrite

```
odoo.define('my_module.my_report', function (require) {
'use strict';
var myWidget = AbstractAction.extend(ControlPanelMixin, {
        custom_events: {
             },
        }
        core.action_registry.add('my_report', myWidget );

        return myWidget 
   });
});
```

I have tried inheriting using the following:

```
var InheritedWidget = require('my_module.my_report);
```

and also:

```
var InheritedWidget = core.action_registry.get('my_report');
```

and when I tried to override, nothing seems to happen:

```
InheritedWidget.include({
    custom_events: {
     //My custom code goes here
       }
})
```

Do you know how to override this widget or method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the `custom_events` of an existing widget.

```
var InheritedWidget = require('my_module.my_report'); 

InheritedWidget.include({
    custom_events: _.extend({}, InheritedWidget.prototype.custom_events, {
        //My custom code goes here
    }),
});
```

For more details refer to the [event system](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#event-system) documentation.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but what I am trying to acomplish is to overwrite the widget, after was added as action_registry, the first part description is an example of what I whant to overwrite

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, check my edit.

Comment: Thank you, it worked passing the ```propotype.custom_events```